# WFA C# Clipboad Monitor bug - link duplications

Tags: c#, clipboard

I wrote clipboard listener WFA on C#. There is a strange bug. When I copy link from address bar of any browser - it makes a duplicate (the same link appers two times in output window). When I copy plain text or link from page or any other place - everething works fine.

Debugging the app show that listener invokes two times in the first case.

Any Ideas why it is happens? Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class ClassCapture: Form
{
    string bufferText;
    private const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x0308;
    private IntPtr _clipboardViewerNext;

    public ClassCapture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void start_capture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addToChain();
    }

    private void stop_capture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeFromChain();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        removeFromChain();
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

    public void addToChain()
    {
        _clipboardViewerNext = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle); 
    }

    public void removeFromChain()
    {
        ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, _clipboardViewerNext);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);    // Process the message 

        if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
        {
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                bufferText = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);      
                if (bufferText != "") {
                    ClipboardHistory.Text = ClipboardHistory.Text + bufferText + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem putting all the string into HashSet before displaying - that's way  duplicates were filtered.
I still didn't get why copying links from browser's adress bar invokes listener two times, but final result is acceptable for me.

```
HashSet<string> textHistory = new HashSet<string>();

// ....

            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                bufferText = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);      // Clipboard text
                if (bufferText != "") {
                    textHistory.Add(bufferText);
                    ClipboardHistory.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, textHistory);
                }
            }
```